# Validation Rule - User input cannot be left blank - Python

Tags: python, regex, validation

I'm currently working on a program that has a validation rule for a name, which doesn't allow any punctuation to be entered. The input is stored in a variable, name, and then stored in a file later on. I have already got the punctuation sorted out. However, when I went back to test my program, I realised that if I left the field blank, the program would accept my input. Here is that part of my code:

```
n = True
while n == True:
    name = input("\nPlease enter your name:\n")
    invalidName = re.search("[^A-Za-z]+",name)

    if invalidName:
        print("No special characters will be accepted.")
    else:
        print("Accepted.")
        name = name.lower()
        name = name.title()
        n = False
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone came up with something to make it so that the user input must have something entered for the program to accept it.

Comment: Why not just check the length of the string? Or, probably more simply, `not name`

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of that. But, how would I do that? :)

EDIT: Never mind, I've found another fix. Thanks, though :P

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks a lot for the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
elif not name:
    print("You must type something in!")
```

after the `if` statement

Comment: You, sir, are amazing! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Glad i could help! :)